# c++ using std:string v char* in a base class - base class has a redudant copy of the string

Tags: c++, string, pointers, inheritance

In the class below from this [tutorial](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/121-pointers-and-references-to-the-base-class-of-derived-objects/) it says that

> you can also make m_speak a std::string, but the downside of doing so
>   is that each Animal will contain a redundant copy of the “speak”

I'm trying to understand this, how would using `string` instead of `char*` only create a redundant copy of `string` and not a `char*`.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class Animal
{
protected:
    std::string m_name;
    const char* m_speak;

    // We're making this constructor protected because
    // we don't want people creating Animal objects directly,
    // but we still want derived classes to be able to use it.
    Animal(std::string name, const char* speak)
        : m_name(name), m_speak(speak)
    {
    }

public:
    std::string getName() { return m_name; }
    const char* speak() { return m_speak; }
};

class Cat: public Animal
{
public:
    Cat(std::string name)
        : Animal(name, "Meow")
    {
    }
};

class Dog: public Animal
{
public:
    Dog(std::string name)
        : Animal(name, "Woof")
    {
    }
};
```

Comment: Because a `std::string` contains the string, a `const char *` merely points at it.

Answer (score 0):

With the constructor:

```
Cat(std::string name) : Animal(name, "Meow")
```

"Meow" is a constant and will have an address in memory. The compiler will use this same constant for every `Cat`. All `Cat` objects' `m_speak` variables will point to that one location.

If you make `m_speak` a `std::string`, the variable `m_speak` will copy "Meow" into its internal buffer. This will happen everytime you create a cat, so there will be many copies.

The same thing applies to `Dog` and "Woof".

Answer (score 0):

`const char*` is a pointer. A pointer stores the memory address of an object (the first character of the string in this case). In this case, the member of each instance points to the same string, so there are no duplicates of the content of the string.

`std::string` is not a pointer. Each `std::string` object has their own buffer where the contents are stored, so each instance has the contents of the string stored by the member.